# Single step a process by one assembly instruction

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, ptrace

When you execute a single step operation using ptrace does the process do one "line" of code or does it do one line of assembly instead. If it's the former case is there a way to step a process in linux by one processor instruction only?

I mean to do this within the kernel but the GDB source is kind of large and it's hard to track exactly what it's doing to do it's ASM singlestepping. I want to single step a process it's just that I'm not sure what the exact behavior of ptrace's single step is (just 1 instruction or more?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does one line of assembly. You can verify this by opening two sessions, in one session you can have your program running which displays the contents of IP register( EIP in 32 bit and RIP in 64 bit) and in other run objdump using the following command - objdump -d -j.code  | less and verify

Answer (score 0):

Use gdb: http://condor.depaul.edu/glancast/373class/docs/gdb.html#Running_the_Program_being_Debugged

If you have access to the source code or debug symbols, you can step one line at a time. If you don't, you'll have to step one instruction at a time.

Comment: For some reason my edit didn't stick I mean to do this inside the linux kernel, I'm not sure if ptrace_request(SINGLESTEP...) will do exactly what I want.

Comment: Are you saying you intend to single-step the kernel? Or that you want the kernel to do the single-stepping of a process?

Comment: Of a process I already know you can single step the kernel with KGDB modules.